# Sending android intent telegram chatbot

Tags: android, telegram, chatbot

Is it possible to send implicit intent from telegram bot which runs on android phone?
Or maybe other way to open application like google map centered in defined position from the bot?

Answer (score 2):

Android intent is app-only specific feature. That can't be used for chat-bot.

But if you want to allow Telegram bot user to open Google Maps app by click - you can use [Geo URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_URI_scheme) for URL that you show for user:

- Android devices: `geo:33.4444,-111.2222?z=3`
- iOS something like: `comgooglemaps://?center=33.4444,-111.2222&zoom=3` as by default they use Apple Maps with `map://` protocol.